# Как передать переменную в кавычки (массив)?

Tags: php

У меня есть переменная, которую нужно вставить в строку массива. Как это сделать?

Мои переменные:

```
$_1 = $array['query'][0]['online'];
$_2 = $array['query'][1]['online'];
```

Куда надо вставить:

```
    $data = array(
'type' => 'table',
'access_token' => '',
'v' => '5.131',
'code' => '
return {
"title": "Мониторинг серверов",
"head": [
    {
        "text": "Сервер"
    },
    {
        "text": "сюда",
        "align": "center"
    }
],
```

Comment: ну поставь переменную вместо `'сюда'`, в чём проблема

Comment: Возвращает просто ее название, но не само число переменной

Comment: если вставлять в двойные кавычки - всё нормально будет....(изучи https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php    отличие одинарных от двойных)

Comment: По-прежнему возвращает название переменной..

Comment: ...Чем докажешь?

Comment: В 'code' какая-то ерунда... код вырван откуда-то не корректно) а "переменную вставить в строку массива" вам ответил Алексей, ознакомьтесь с синтаксисом

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае можно сделать пару вариантов

1. `"' . $_1 . $_2 . '"`
2. Предварительно делаем строку за счёт HEREDOC

   ```
    $text = <<<TEXT
    return {
        "title": "Мониторинг серверов",
        "head": [
            {
                "text": "Сервер"
            },
            {
                "text": "$_1 $_2",
                "align": "center"
            }
        ],
    }
    TEXT;
   ```

   Потом вставляем:

   ```
    'code' => $text;
   ```